# In D3's zoom behavior, bubble the mousewheel event if maximally zoomed out

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, scroll, zooming

I'm using D3's zoom behavior on a large world map.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 100]);
```

It works great, providing a natural zoom functionality and disabling the usual scroll activity one expects from a MouseWheel event, as it should.

However, when the map takes up the whole screen, I worry that users will get frustrated if they try to scroll down using the mouse wheel when the map is zoomed all the way out. Is there a way to bubble up to this behavior only in that circumstance?

A good example is the way a scrollable DIV on the page will scroll down when the mouse wheel is used over top of it. But when it reaches the bottom, the page itself resumes scrolling down.

I don't know a lot about event bubbling, but I do see that the D3 zoom behavior does called a `d3.event.preventDefault().`

Comment: In your zoom handler, you would need to check whether the source of the event (accessible through `d3.event`) is the mousewheel and only execute the handler code if it isn't.

Comment: I don't think that would be enough, @LarsKotthoff, since the mousewheel event (and the `preventDefault` call) is being handled by the internal d3 zoom behaviour code, not by the custom zoom handling code.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without changing the source code.  I tried to clone the source event and re-dispatch it on the parent node, but although the parent node is registering the event it still doesn't scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/v2ab2/

Comment: Thanks guys! Right now I'm manually checking for a zoom value of 1 in the zoom callback and calling window.scrollBy(0, 10) if true. Hacky, but seems to work.